# Mysql Stored Procedure performance when using user-defined variable

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures, user-defined-variables

I have a mysql 8.0 stored procedure which uses a start_date parameter in the logic.

If start_date is "set" (e.g., set @start_date = '2023-01-01', the query executes in a fraction of a second.

However, if I declare a local variable (i.e., declare start_date date default '2023-01-01', or if I hard-code the start_date , the query takes almost 350 seconds.

Why might there be such a dramatic difference in performance?  The output is correct and as expected in both cases -- but one just takes an enormous amount of time.

Below is the EXPLAIN output when "setting" the variable:

[image]

and the output when "declaring" the local variable is below.  Why is the row count so dramatically different?

[image]

Comment: Seems like `'2023-0-01'` is an invalid date??

Comment: @Rick James -- thanks, it was a typo when posting the question. In actuality it was correctly formatted to '20230101' or '2023-01-01'; I'll edit the post.

Comment: Now we need to see the query.  Better yet, let's see the Stored Proc.

Answer (score 1):

```
select date('2023-0-01') is null; --> 1
```

That is, your string is treated as a `NULL`.

Nulls often work in surprising ways.

If you like help in optimizing the query, let's see it.  (The `EXPLAIN` is not enough.)

Comment: Need to see the query, stored procedure and TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name' for each table involved, please.